# Part-time vs full-time. How is this category called?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I want to give name to a column where values will be "full-time studies" or "part-time studies". How should I name the column?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for software elements is specifically out of site scope according to our [help].

Comment: @tchrist - "software element" is just an example. I am asking how is that correctly called in English, which looks like more in scope here than somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Enrollment Status* would be a good choice.

From [Purdue Global](https://catalog.purdueglobal.edu/policy-information/financial/enrollment-status-definition-academic-year/):

> Enrollment Status and Definition of an Academic Year
>
> Your enrollment status can impact financial aid eligibility.
>
> The U.S. Department of Veterans Affairs may have different definitions
> for full-time and part-time status. You should consult the
> University's Certifying Official if you are receiving veterans
> benefits.
>
> Undergraduate
>
> An academic year consists of three terms of instruction, during which
> a full-time student will complete at least 36 credit hours. Thus,
> enrollment status is defined as:
>
> ```
> Full-time: 12 credit hours per term
> Three-quarter-time: 9 credit hours per term
> Half-time: 6 credit hours per term
> ```

From the [US Department of Education](https://studentaidhelp.ed.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/279/%7E/enrollment-status):

> Enrollment Status
>
> Reported by the school the student attended, indicates whether the
> student is (or was) full-time, three-quarter time, half-time, less
> than half-time, withdrawn, graduated, etc.